# How to prove that a group is simple only from its class equation

Tags: group-theory

Can someone give me a hint/solution how to prove that a group is simple if its class equation is $60=1+15+20+12+12$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A normal subgroup is a union of conjugacy classes. And of course any subgroup contains the identity, and has order dividing the order of the group. So it's enough to consider all possible submultisets of $\{1,15,20,12,12\}$ containing $1$ and check that none (apart from the trivial ones) is a factor of $60$.

Comment: What do you mean by submultisets? @Chris Eagle

Comment: I am confused as the class equation for $s_3$ can be written 6=1+2+3 and all of these are factors of 6 yet $s_3$ is not simple? do we have to take away 1 for the identity element in each conjugacy class? Hence looking at {14, 19, 11, 11} as factors of 60 in the original case?