# Proving that a group is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetry

I want to solve the following:

Let $I$ be the group of isometries that preserve the orientation of the icosahedron. Use the class formula to show that $I$ is a simple group (i.e. It does not have proper normal subgroups) of order 60.

Well, the thing is that I dont know how to use the class formula, I have checked [How to prove that a group is simple only from its class equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279571/how-to-prove-that-a-group-is-simple-only-from-its-class-equation), but I dont know if it works in my case. Can you help me to prove this please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

My class formula:

$|G|= |Z(G)|+ \sum_{g \in R´} [G:Z(g)]$

where $Z(g):= G_g$ the isotropy group given by the action conjugation. And $R´$ is the set of representatives of all te non-trivial conjugacy classes

Comment: Have you tried to compute the conjugacy classes of $I$?

Comment: Well my goal is to prove that  $\sum =60$ and then $|Z(G)|=0 $ but I dont know if this is right or how to compute explicity $\sum $

Comment: The identity is always in the center, so $|Z(G)| \geq 1$.  The answer in the linked post is very good; take some time to think about it.

Comment: Ok, :) let me check because I have found http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888911/showing-that-group-of-orientation-preserving-isometries-of-icosahedron-is-a-simp and I think it is better , right?

Comment: Well I dont know what is a submultiset :)